# How to make create-vue parse JSX without problems (as VueCLI does)

Tags: vue.js, jsx, vue-cli, create-vue

I use `JSX` extensively to customize `Naive-UI` library elements. But after migrating from `VueCLI` to `create-vue`, I noticed it looks like `create-vue` doesn't understand JSX in `.vue` file at all. For example it throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` for this:

```
const x = <div>Hi all</div>;
```

But VueCLI does understand... So the question is:
How to make `create-vue` parse `JSX` without problems (as `VueCLI` does)?

PS. Here is vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vueJsx from "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Please share the vite.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use JSX in `.vue` files, make sure to use `<script lang="jsx">` (or "tsx" if using TypeScript)